# Calculating the limit of $\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x}$ as $x \rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Show that the $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x}=0$

My attempt

$$\begin{align}
\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x}*\frac{\cos(x)+1}{\cos(x)+1}&=\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\cos^2(x)}{x(1+\cos(x))}\\\\
&=\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x(1+\cos(x))}\\\\
&=\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}*\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}\\\\
&=1*\frac{0}{2}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$ $$QED$$

Since $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$ by the sandwich theorem.

i know this is correct however i would like it if anyone could show me the natural argument of using power series instead.

Recall the definition of the cosine function by the power series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}, \forall x \in \mathbb R$$

Also can anyone show me how to show that the radius of convergence of the cosine power series is $$\infty$$

Comment: You can just as easily prove the more precise $\lim_{x \to 0} (1-\cos(x))/x^2 = 1/2$.

Comment: As a side comment, the limit is $\cos'(0)$ by the definition of the derivative.

Answer (score 5):

If you insist in power series:

$$\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{24}-\ldots\implies \cos x-1=x\left(-\frac x{2}+\frac{x^3}{24}-\ldots\right)\implies$$

$$\frac{\cos x-1}x=\left(-\frac x{2}+\frac{x^3}{24}-\ldots\right)=-\frac x2+\mathcal O(x^3)\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}0$$

Comment: may i ask what $$\mathcal O(x^3)$$ is?

Comment: @Gibberish A function $f(x)$ is $O(g(x))$ as $x\to x_0$ if there exists a number $C>0$, such that $|f(x)|\le C|g(x)|$ for $x$ in some neighborhood of $x_0$.  Here, $f(x)=\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}+\frac x2$, $g(x)=x^3$, and $x_0=0$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks for the accurate, as usual, explanation given, Mark.

Comment: You're welcome Don.  My pleasure to help.

Comment: ahh I've not learned anything like this before thanks for the explanation though.

Comment: @Gibberish You could imagine a Lagrange remainder to be replaced by the $\mathcal O(x^3)$ since we know that$$\left|\frac{\cos x-1}x+\frac12x+0x^2\right|\le\frac{|\cos\xi|}{4!}x^3\le\frac1{24}x^3$$which holds for all $x$.

Comment: Why did you need that last step? Just cause big-O looks nice?

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\cos(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$.  Therefore, we can write

$$\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!} \tag 1$$

Hence, inasmuch as the lowest order power in the series is $1$, all terms approach $0$ as $x\to 0$.

Interestingly, we immediately have from $(1)$ that

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}=\frac12$$

---

**Second Question:**

The radius of convergence for the power series for the cosine function can be found using the ratio test.  Note that the series converges when

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\le1$$

where $a_n=\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$.  Proceeding we see that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x^2}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}=0$$

for all $x$.  Hence, the radius of convergence is indeed $\infty$.

---

**ASIDE:**

Note that $1-\cos(x)=2\sin^2(x/2)$.  Therefore, we can write

$$\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x}=-\underbrace{\left(\frac{\sin(x/2)}{x/2}\right)}_{\to1}\,\underbrace{\sin(x/2)}_{\to0}$$

Comment: @carmichael561 Yes, it was.  I've edited and thank you.

Comment: Very nice further explanation. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you my friend!  Always nice to see you here.

Comment: for the second question how does showing that the limit =0 mean that it's radius of convergence is $\infty$?

Comment: @Gibberish The radius of convergence is the supremum of values of $x$ for which the limit is less than $1$.  So, $$R=\frac{1}{\underbrace{\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|}_{=0}}=\infty$$

Comment: could we use the ratio test for the first question?

Comment: @Gibberish I don't understand your question here.  In the first question, we are asked to evaluate a limit using power series.  We proceeded to do just that with the a priori knowledge that the series converges in a neighborhood of $x=0$.  In the second question, we are asked to show that the radius of convergence.  We found that $R=\infty$, which means that the Taylor series for the cosine converges for all fixed values of $x$ and not just in a bounded neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: It's a problem on my tutorial sheets, for the real analysis course i'm studying, i was just wondering if we could use the ratio test on the power series of cos(x)-1/x instead of the approach you and other discussed above. where $$\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}$$  and $$a_n=\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}$$

Comment: Oh, I see.  Yes, we can.  And we find that the radius of convergence of that series is also $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

using the series  of $\cos x$ you have:
$$
\cos x-1 =-1 +\cos x= -1+1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+o(x^3)= -\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^3)
$$